# OEM Product Key from Product ID?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation, oem

I re-installed my Windows 7 installation and I am being asked for the Product Key. But alas, stupid me, I had jotted down the Product ID and not the actual Product Key. Unfortunately, I lost the Windows case where the key is at, so I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve the product key just by using the Product ID?

Comment: Product ID = generic identification of *what* version/type of Windows you're installing, which is the same for everyone.  Product Key = your *unique* copy of Windows (i.e. the only thing you paid for).

Comment: Not exactly. There are two kinds of Microsoft PIDs. There are the PIDs that Breakthrough is referring to such as X16-96072 which refers to refers to a specific version of Windows 7, and there's the GUID PIDs, such as 00345-640-9009001-00001 which is a (contrived) PID that would be derived from a product key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product key is stored in the registry, and you can retrieve it from there with tools like [KeyFinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/). Beware that if you bought the system pre-installed, the distributor most likely used *their* product key for the initial setup, which won't work with your installation media.

Comment: +1.  I've noted on several laptops that the OEM installation key did *not* work (the one I recovered from the installed copy of Windows), but the one on the actual install media / bottom of the laptop *did* work.

Comment: This depends on the windows version you are using. E.g. installling a shop bought regular windows 7 on a Dell witll ask for a key delivered with that product (or the key from the CoA on the bottom). But a OEM DVD should check the firmware/BIOS for a key and not ask for one.  Firmware key and regelar DVD do not work, your two items must match.

Answer (score 2):

The product ID is completely different from the actual product key, and the latter cannot be derived from the former. The product ID is generated during installation and contains information like the exact Windows version, channel the licence came from (retail, OEM, MSDN etc.), as well as the locale; it is used when getting technical support from Microsoft, it does not prove ownership of a Windows licence.

If you backed up your previous Windows installation, then you should be able to use a utility like [Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder) to load the correct registry hive and read the product key. If not, then I'm afraid your only option is to buy a new copy of Windows, since you've lost or erased all traces of your previous licence.

Comment: `the latter cannot be derived from the former` That's not correct, I remember some group releasing a tool that could convert a PID back to a key. I don't recall if it was specific to a particular Windows family or version (eg 9x, XP) or if it required any brute-forcing, but it definitely did happen at one point and was big news in "the scene". (No, I'm not talking about deriving the PID from the key to check its validity.) I'm trying to find a copy or post about it, but all I can find now are key-finders or at best, ones that extract it from the PID in the registry instead of the GUID string.

Answer (score 1):

Your OEM will have affixed the COA with the needed key to the computer.  As others have noted, your only real choice is to purchse a new copy of Windows 7 and likely re-install as the key for a retail copy will not work with the OEM install.

Answer (score 0):

Win 7 stores the key in the registry ("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentrentVersion\DigitalProductId"), but it's binary so that your average 'human' doesn't interfere with MS's quest for more money. 
You can get it out with a little VB Script though.

Save the code below as eg "getkey.vbs", run it (double-click) and a little pop-up msg tells you your key. Use CTRL+C and CTRL+V to paste it into notepad.

```
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  registryLocation = '"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentrentVersion\DigitalProductId"';

  MsgBox ConvertHumanReadable(WshShell.RegRead(registryLocation))

  Function ConvertHumanReadable(Key)
    Const KeyOffset = 52
    i = 28
    Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
    Do
    Current = 0
    x = 14
    Do
    Current = Current * 256
    Current = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Current
    Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Current \ 24) And 255
    Current = Current Mod 24
    x = x -1
    Loop While x >= 0
        i = i -1
        KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Current + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
        If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
           i = i -1
           KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
        End If
    Loop While i >= 0
    ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
  End Function
```

I don't know about win8 or win10, but theoretically all you need to do is change the 'registryLocation' value in the code (if at all).

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP wants the Product **Key** not Product **ID**.